# While loop waits without stopping until the time.sleep finishes

Tags: python-3.x, time, while-loop

I have a while loop in a thread which checks a webstream every 10 minutes.

```
while not stop_event.is_set():
    time.sleep(600)
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    if response.status_code==200:
        print("UPDATED")
    else:
        print("NOT UPDATED")
```

But if the `not stop_event.is_set()` changed to `False` before 10 minutes, Still the while loop waits 10 minutes and executes the rest of the code and then exits

```
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    if response.status_code==200:
        print("UPDATED")
    else:
        print("NOT UPDATED")
```

I want to quit immediately as the `not stop_event.is_set()` changed to `False` without witing `time.sleep(600)` to finish

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `time.sleep`, which is blocking, you could use [`threading.Event.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event.wait) which will return immediately if the internal flag is set:

```
while not stop_event.is_set():
    if stop_event.wait(600):
        break # or use "return" if you want the entire function to end
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("UPDATED")
    else:
        print("NOT UPDATED")
```

A reproducible example:

```
import time
import threading


def run_in_thread(stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        if stop_event.wait(5):
            print(f"{time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime())}: Stopped.")
            return
        print(f"{time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime())}: Running.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stop_event = threading.Event()
    t = threading.Thread(target=run_in_thread, args=(stop_event,))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(16)
    stop_event.set()
```

Comment: I want to stop the loop entirely when the external function set the flag to True

Comment: `break` breaks the loop immediately if the event is set during the wait timeout, doesnt wait for the timeout to expire as was the case with `time.sleep`... if your function has more code out of the loop you can use `return` or call `sys.exit()` instead of `break`. The only problem is if the event is set when the `requests.get` call is being executed, which is also blocking, in that case it will stop on the next iteration once the request returns.

Comment: Thank you for your perfect explanation....this works